# CursorAdapter strange behaviour

Tags: java, android, listview, cursor, android-cursoradapter

In my app I show some info and depending on the value I change the color of the textView.

```java
public class DealsAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private Context mContext;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public DealsAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, true);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.deals_row, parent, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
         Text View percent = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvPercent);
          percent.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.D_PERCENT)));
          float percentV = cursor.getFloat(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.D_PERCENT));
          if (percentV >= 41 && percentV <= 70) {
            // Orange
            percent.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F58549"));
        } else if (percentV >= 71) {
            // Green
            percent.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#17D11D"));
        }
}
```

The problem is after i scroll up and down the colors start getting mixed up but the values stay the same.

Any advice?

Edit: In the xml I set the color to red and only change if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't explicitly setting a colour if `percentV < 41`. This means the item will retain whatever colour that view had previously, giving unpredictable results.

This is because each item's `View` may be reused for performance reasons. If you scroll one item off the top of the screen, the same `View` may be used for the new item appearing at the bottom of the screen, to save the cost of inflating a new one each time. You have to explicitly set the default colour in `bindView()`, or else the `View` will retain whatever colour it had for the last item it contained.

Comment: I set the color in xml to red and only change if needed.

Comment: You can't do that. Views in a ListView are reused. If you scroll one item of the top of the screen, the same View is used for the new item appearing at the bottom of the screen, for performance reasons. You have to explicitly set the default colour in `bindView()`.

Comment: Oh i forgot that views are reused, its working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the percentV is < than 41.

```
if (percentV >= 41 && percentV <= 70) {
  // Orange
  percent.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F58549"));
} else if (percentV >= 71) {
  // Green
  percent.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#17D11D"));
} else {
  // DEFAULT color (if percentV < 41)
  percent.setTextColor(DEFAULT COLOR);
}
```